# PHP syntax error for concatenation of string with the . operator

Tags: php

I know its a silly question, but I can't get around with it, I am new to php:

```
$sqlCheckUser = "SELECT * FROM `user` where `email` = '".  .$email ."' OR `username` = '". .$username ."'";
```

This line is giving this error : *syntax error, unexpected '.'*

Can someone please help why is this giving error in VS code, also I've declared all the variables mentioned.
Thanks

Comment: You have two dots before `$email`. Remove one of them.

Comment: You have an extra dot before email

Comment: same extra dot before $username too. This method however is not safe - use prepared statements when using user supplied data in a SQL query

Comment: Thanks @Pupil this helped me. Although I'd tried removing the dot earlier but realized now I didn't have the root access to save the file, so it was not saved, hence giving the error. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: If you are new to PHP you may as well learn about SQL injection attacks and how to avoid it : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php . This will also ease you the way you write SQL queries as you won't have to concat strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
$sqlCheckUser = "SELECT * FROM `user` where `email` = '".$email ."' OR `username` = '".$username ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra dot before `email` and before `username`
like so:

```
`$sqlCheckUser = "SELECT * FROM user where email = '".  $email ."' OR username = '" .$username ."'";`
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 dot to concatenate strings in PHP.

```
echo "a" . "b";  // "ab"
```

However, this is a bad way to make SQL query because it is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Use prepare statement instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php